# Using a Directx Library (dll) in XNA

Tags: xna, directx

I've Directx Library which I'm able to use in any C# Windows Form Application. If I try to use same dll on a XNA project in the same way adding referances and importling library's the XNA project gives the error Assembly for the library is required.

How can I solve this problem or Using a Directx Library is impossible to use in XNA or the ways using a Directx Library in XNA and Win-Form are different?

(note: a directx library means a library uses directx for special functions)

Thanks!

Comment: As Neil Knight says, there may well be a way to accomplish what you want through XNA. Tell us what you want to do and we'll see if there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

XNA uses DirectX under the hood, so I don't see why you'd need to use a DirectX library.  If the functions in the library are part of the DirectX SDK, there may well be an alternative function in XNA.

Comment: There is not any alternative, but my friend has solved the problem as he tolds, tomorrow i will check his project.